# Mule 4, get uri params with Anypoint application

Tags: mule, anypoint-studio

I'm new in Mulesoft, I'm following Quickstart guide. In Step 2 (https://developer.mulesoft.com/guides/quick-start/developing-your-first-mule-application), I need to receive variables from URI in this way:

[{'id' : attributes.uriParams.productId}]

But when I try my GET I have the following error in console:

**Message : "Cannot coerce Array ([{id: "2" as String {class: "java.lang.String"}}]) to Object 1| [{'id' : attributes.uriParams.productId}] ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ Trace: at main (line: 1, column: 1)" evaluating expression: "[{'id' : attributes.uriParams.productId}]". Error type : MULE:EXPRESSION Element : get:\products(productId):test_daniel-config/processors/1 @ test6_db_connection:test_daniel.xml:133 (Select) Element XML : SELECT product.,CONCAT('["', (GROUP_CONCAT(variant.picture SEPARATOR '","')),'"]') AS pictures,CONCAT('[', GROUP_CONCAT('{"',variant.identifierType, '":"', variant.identifier, '"}'),']') AS identifiersFROM product INNER JOIN variant ON product.uuid = variant.productUUIDWHERE product.uuid = :id; #[[{'id' : attributes.uriParams.productId}]] *

Any Ideas? Thanks!

Comment: is there a particular reason why this is [{'id' : attributes.uriParams.productId}] like this and not like {'id' : attributes.uriParams.productId} ? i am assuming you are supposed to pass a unique productId as a uri param to extract it not an array of productID's? same thing when you are trying to use it in where clause in query  #[[{'id' : attributes.uriParams.productId}]]  its being treated as an array. its not possible to construct a query where you can use an array as an argument.

Comment: In the guide they use  [{'id' : attributes.uriParams.productId}], but I try  {'id' : attributes.uriParams.productId} and it works, thanks!

Comment: i will post it as my answer could you please accept since it helped you :)

Answer (score 1):

cannot coerce Array to object error pop's up when you are using an array where you were supposed to use an object.

in the exception above the uri-param should be treated as ab object i.e. enclosed in {} but its being treated as an array of objects [{}].

this is causing the error.